# Pass data from code behind and ViewModel to another ViewModel

Tags: xaml, mvvm, viewmodel

I have a View which has 2 sub views on it and a ViewModel is assigned to each view:

```
ViewParent - ViewModelParent
{ 
   ViewA - ViewModelA
   ViewB - ViewModelB
}
```

The `ViewParent` structure likes below.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <local:AView DataContext="{Binding ViewModelA, Mode=TwoWay}"></localViews:AView>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <localViews:BView DataContext="{Binding ViewModelB, Mode=TwoWay}"></localViews:BView>
</StackPanel>
```

Now in code behind of `ViewA`, I have an event to select a row in a gridview.

```
  private void radGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RadGridView grv = sender as RadGridView;                       

            if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
            {
               var row = grv.SelectedItem as SomeClass;
               if(condition)
                  // Enable a button in ViewB.
```

What I want is to pass `row` to `ViewModelB`. Also, I want to enable a button in ViewB. Finally I want to pass a few integers from `ViewModelA` to `ViewModelB`.

How to do it? I thought about constructor injection but still without clear idea.

Comment: ViewModelParent should have a reference to each child vm, right? So Give vmA a SelectedRow property, with `PropertyChanged`, and bind that in ViewA. Give vmA a SelectedRowChanged event. Raise it when the selected row changes. ViewModelParent sets up a handler for that event when it creates vmA, and in the handler it sets a property on vmB like `bool CanDoWhatever`. `CanDoWhatever` enables the command that the button is bound to, and sees that the command's CanExecuteChanged event is raised.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, yes. ViewModelParent does have a reference to each child vm. And VmA has a SelectedItem property with `PropertyChanged` already. And I am not sure the rest I can do in VmB.

Comment: Do whatever you have to with the tools you've got. Maybe give vmB a property `bool IsMyPuppyDogButtonEnabled { get; set; }` that raises PropertyChanged. Have the parent vm set that property appropriately and on the Button in XAML `IsEnabled="{Binding IsMyPuppyDogButtonEnabled}"`. There's a million ways to do it. Bottom line: Viewmodels manage state among themselves. Views sit there observing their viewmodels' properties, and responding to changes in those properties.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I see about binding button a property. For the SelectedRow property, how to pass it to ViewModelB? Using constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of typing here, but there's no difficult logic and there's nothing that'll turn into a bug and bite you.

1. Make sure `ParentViewModel` has references to `ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB` (as I understand it you're already there).
2. Give `ViewModelA` a `SelectedRowChanged` event:

   ```
   public event EventHandler SelectedRowChanged;
   ```
3. Give `ViewModelB` an `IsMyButtonEnabled` property (but name it better than that; you need the name to indicate *which* button its referring to)

   ```
   private bool _isMyButtonEnabled;
   public bool IsMyButtonEnabled {
       get { return _isMyButtonEnabled; }
       set { 
           _isMyButtonEnabled = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsMyButtonEnabled));
       }
   }
   ```
4. In `ViewB`, bind the button's `IsEnabled` property to that property:

   ```
   <Button
       ...
       IsEnabled="{Binding IsMyButtonEnabled}"
       ...
   ```
5. Give both `ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB` a `SelectedRow` property.

   ```
   private SomeClass _selectedRow;
   public SomeClass SelectedRow {
       get { return _selectedRow; }
       set { 
           _selectedRow = value;
           OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedRow));
           /*
               DO ADDITIONAL STUFF HERE:

               VMA: 
                   SelectedRowChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

               VMB:
                   Set IsMyButtonEnabled to whatever is appropriate based on
                   the selected row. 
            */
       }
   }
   ```
6. `ParentViewModel` sets up a handler for `ViewModelA.SelectedRowChanged`, which it can do because it has a reference to its instance of `ViewModelA`. Then the handler tells `ViewModelB` to do whatever needs to be done when SelectedRow changes. Another way to do this would be to give `ViewModelB` a reference to `ViewModelA`, and have it handle `ViewModelA.SelectedRowChanged`. But as a rule, you want your child viewmodels to be more loosely coupled than that. You don't want B to *depend* on having a sibling of type A. But the parent *already* depends on having both of those children. In for a penny, in for a pound. You can't get any more wet.

   ```
   ...
   //  Constructor or someplace
   this.VMA = new ViewModelA();
   this.VMA.SelectedRowChanged += ViewModelA_SelectedRowChanged;
   ...

   void ViewModelA_SelectedRowChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //  VMB.SelectedItem's setter will enable the button appropriately
       VMB.SelectedItem = VMA.SelectedItem;
   }
   ```

You really "should" be doing the button thing with a Command, and enabling the Command instead of having an `Is*ButtonEnabled` property. That's a more versatile and powerful way to do things. But we can take things one step at a time.

Comment: In step 6, is it a typo? `VMB.SelectedItem = VMB.SelectedItem;`. I understand most of them except the SelectedItem in both places matches each other.

Comment: @Bigeyes Sure was a typo. Thanks. Fixed it. The SelectedItem properties *don't* match -- there's a part that differs, which I put in a comment block ("DO ADDITIONAL STUFF HERE") explaining how each of the two A/B vm classes adds its own special bit of code.

Comment: The thing is the button in ViewB is still disabled even I set it as true in the setter part of `SelectedItem` property block(ViewB). By the way I invoke the row change event in the ViewA's code behind rather than ViewModelA.cs. Not sure if it is the cause. I saw you put the selectedItem change event in the setter part of ViewModelA. But I have to place it in the code behind class.

Comment: My bad, sorry about it. I find the error. In delegate command `CanExecuteTrue`, I set it as false. I didn't pay attention to it. Now it works out. ;-)